# How to get filled interface instance as a parameter of a method after executing the method?

Tags: c#

I have a method that fills an instance of an interface as bellow:

```
private static void Caller() {
    IOrder order = null;

    MakeOrder(order);

    //order is empty
}

private static void MakeOrder(IOrder order) {
    order = new Order
    {
        PeriodCount = mciOrderInfo.PeriodCount,
        Quantity = mciOrderInfo.Quantity,
        ShoppingItemId = shoppingItem
    };
}
```

After executing this method `MakeOrder` the `Caller` will get `order = null` but this method fills `order` as above.

I know if the type of parameter was a class `Order` instead of interface `IOrder`, it will be filled and accessible in `Caller` method.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpelst way is to use `return`:

```
private static void Caller()
{
    IOrder order = MakeOrder();
}

private static IOrder MakeOrder()
{
    return new Order
    {
        PeriodCount = mciOrderInfo.PeriodCount,
        Quantity = mciOrderInfo.Quantity,
        ShoppingItemId = shoppingItem
    };
}
```

Or, if for some reason you want to do otherwise, you can use `ref`/`out`:

```
private static void Caller()
{
    IOrder order;

    MakeOrder(out order);
}

private static void MakeOrder(out IOrder order)
{
    order = new Order
    {
        PeriodCount = mciOrderInfo.PeriodCount,
        Quantity = mciOrderInfo.Quantity,
        ShoppingItemId = shoppingItem
    };
}
```

[`ref`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx) passes the parameter *by reference*, which means if you modify it inside your function the caller's variable will be modified.

[`out`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx) is basically the same, except the caller doesn't have to initialize the variable, it's always the responsibility of the callee.

Yet another way would be to pass an instance and fill its properties:

```
private static void Caller()
{
    IOrder order = new Order();
    MakeOrder(order);
}

private static void MakeOrder(IOrder order)
{
    order.PeriodCount = mciOrderInfo.PeriodCount;
    order.Quantity = mciOrderInfo.Quantity;
    order.ShoppingItemId = shoppingItem;
}
```

This works because classes (and interfaces for that matter) are *reference types*.

You should read this MSDN article: [Passing Reference-Type Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6938f28.aspx).

Comment: Ah, I see. I'm typing on my smartphone and am slow here... ;-)

Comment: @Lucas why an interface parameter needs out or ref but a class parameter does not need?

Comment: @Ali I think you're confused between reference types and reference parameters. I've edited my answer to add a 3rd example without `ref`. You should consider reading a couple tutorials on that matter, because understanding it is really important.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski I got it :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're dealing with multiple variables here.

This line:

```
MakeOrder(order);
```

calls `MakeOrder` with a copy of the *value* of that variable, which currently is `null`. Inside `MakeOrder` you change the *local parameter variable* to a new value, but the original `order` variable on the outside is still `null`.

Perhaps you want to use a return type instead:

```
private static void Caller()
{
    IOrder order = MakeOrder(order);
}

private static IOrder MakeOrder()
{
    return new Order
    {
        PeriodCount = mciOrderInfo.PeriodCount,
        Quantity = mciOrderInfo.Quantity,
        ShoppingItemId = shoppingItem
    };
}
```

Also note that the type of the parameter has nothing to with this, even if you changed `MakeOrder` to take a parameter of type `Order` (a class) you would still have the same problem.